# How can i get the month records in sqlite database?

Tags: android, mysql, database, sqlite

I stored all the details in the database like below.

[image]

I wrote the query for getting the month records but i didn't succeed. The below image has my query.

[image]

Can you please help me how can i get the month records. Here i am getting only 2 records but why my 13th and 12 days are not getting i don't know. I tried so much but i didn't succeed.

Comment: put the code code(between date1 and date2) in brackets and give it a try

Comment: Means: cursor = database.query(DatabaseHelper.DGADATATABLE, columns, "equipid = '"+equipid+"' ,and dateadded BETWEEN '"+start+"' AND '"+end+"'"  , null, null,null, "dateadded DESC");

Comment: no.the query should be like this select * from tablename where equipid='1' and (dateadded BETWEEN date1 AND date2) ORDER BY dateadded DESC;

Comment: i tried that also returns same 2rows result.